# Cognito drop down menu calculation

Tags: cognito-forms

In Cognito forms I have a table where users can select a product from a drop down menu. On the following Performance drop menu, if a user selects and adds more than 1 item can it calculate the total performance number in the total area.

See screenshot: https://ibb.co/f2vkrVg

Comment: There is  no screenshot.

Comment: sorry picture here: https://ibb.co/f2vkrVg

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible using the sum() method of the repeating section / table.

The calculation for your total would be as follows, names of fields may be different.

```
=Tickets.Sum(Performance)
```